# Asp.net MVC - load JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

In my asp.net MVC website, I have a layout file where I load my JavaScript files :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My title</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

</head>
<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerymobile")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="home">
        <div id="divPartialView">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then, I have a main page that use the layout:

```
 @{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBase.cshtml";
 }
```

In this page, I replace the content of my div by a partial view :

```
 $.ajax({
 url: '@Url.Action("MyPage", "Home")',
 data: { myVariable: "variable"},
 cache: false,
 type: "POST",
 dataType: "html",
 success: function (data) {
     $("#divPartialView").html(data);
 },
 error: function () {
     alert("error");
 }
 });
```

My partial View :

```
<div data-role="header">

</div>

<div data-role="content" id="MainContent">

</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

</div>
```

The problem is that in this partial view, I have to load the Jquery mobile scripts again, otherwise it doesn't work... (the header and footer doesn't display correctly)

Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: Read this article: http://www.gajotres.net/how-jquery-mobile-page-handling-affects-javascript-executions/ so you can learn how jQuery Mobile handles JavaScript initialization.

Answer (score 2):

You have a file name `BundleConfig`, this file show you what scripts you load.
This file should contain:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

After that check your layout, your file must contain:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Have a good day.

Comment: Wanted to thank you for your response @marcin-navialek  couldnt remember for the life of me where they loaded in mvc.  You saved me some time!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `@section Scripts{}`

```
<body>
    ...
    //should bottom of body tag.
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerymobile")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

In partial view write all code under Scripts section

```
@section Scripts {
    $.ajax({
        ....
    });
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try it. Sorry if it was a simple question, I'm a beginner in asp.net mvc...

Answer (score 0):

I would put javascript references after loading entire page like:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="home">
        <div id="divPartialView">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
</div>

...     

     <!-- finally here -->
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquerymobile")
     @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to append relative scripts after you append new html (this case your partial) to the page. I'm guessing something like below:

```
...
success: function (data) {
     $("#divPartialView").html(data);
     $("#divPartialView").append('<script src="jquery.mobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
 },
...
```

also make sure this script gets all the pre-requisite scripts.